# Combine two columns with same column name using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have a dataframe (df) where two columns are of different length. I would like to combine these two columns as one column. How do I do that?

The table looks like the following:

| Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_1 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 12 | A1 | 345 |
| A2 | 34 | A2 | 980 |
| A3 | 098 | A3 | 543 |
|  |  | A4 | 8765 |
|  |  | A5 | 765 |

I would like to combine Col_1 as one column in the table. The output should look like the following:

**Desired Output:**

| Col_1 | Col_2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 12 | 345 |
| A2 | 34 | 980 |
| A3 | 098 | 543 |
| A4 |  | 8765 |
| A5 |  | 765 |

What I tried so far?

```
df1 = df.columns[0]
df2 = df.columns[2]
df_merge_col = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Col_1')
```

or

```
df["Col_1"] = df["Col_1"].astype(str) + df["Col_1"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use `np.where` for this task following way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['A1', 'A1'], ['A2', 'A2'], ['A3', None], ['A4', None]])
combined = np.where(df[0].isnull(), df[1], df[0])
df.drop(columns=[0, 1], inplace=True)
df[0] = combined
print(df)
```

output

```
    0
0  A1
1  A2
2  A3
3  A4
```

`np.where` is like ternary operator for `pandas.Series` where column 0 has not value get value from column 1 otherwise from column 0

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generic solution using `MultiIndex` and `stack`.

In summary, it de-duplicates the columns by adding a unique id, which we then use to `stack` the data. The rest is only sorting/cleaning.

```
(df.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns,
                                        df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).cumcount()
                                       ]), axis=1)
   .stack(level=1)
   .sort_index(level=1)
   .droplevel(1)
   .drop_duplicates(subset=df.columns[df.columns.duplicated()])
)
```

output:

```
  Col_1   Col_2  Col_3
0    A1    12.0  345.0
1    A2    34.0  980.0
2    A3    98.0  543.0
3    A4  8765.0    NaN
4    A5   765.0    NaN
```

Comment: I edited a bit the code to avoid modifying the original df, but it's the same

Answer (score 1):

If duplicated columns names for filtering by position use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), then remove NaNs rows by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with outer join:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, :2].dropna(subset=['Col_1'])
df2 = df.iloc[:, 2:].dropna(subset=['Col_1'])
df_merge_col = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Col_1', how='outer')
print (df_merge_col)
  Col_1  Col_2  Col3
0    A1   12.0   345
1    A2   34.0   980
2    A3   98.0   543
3    A4    NaN  8765
4    A5    NaN   765
```

Comment: I have the same problem but with more then 2 columns with the same name . Is there any way to  generalize this solution?

Comment: @ElizaR - hmm, if mozway solution not working the best post new question.